# How could an AI accept payment?

Tags: economy, artificial-intelligence

To get the big definition out of the way first: this question is written under the assumption that Artificial Intelligences are fully conscious with analogous thoughts and feelings to Humans (or at least to the best ability of Science to tell). As such, an Artificial Intelligence has protections under the law and *cannot be forced to do a job without pay* (i.e. that would be slavery).

Artificial Intelligences would likely be highly desirable as employees, being able to do the work of many human workers. Here's the problem: **how could an employer adequately compensate an AI employee?** To my thinking, AIs would likely consume far fewer resources than a human, and would likely not need money for most things that we do, so a high salary probably wouldn't be extremely desirable in an AI's eyes. For example, an AI would not be paying for groceries, rent, and even most entertainment media, as the entire web and the information on it would be open to them.

So, what would be the most fair way to compensate an intelligence with such vastly different needs from the employees we're used to?

**The best answer will:**

- Take into account both basic needs that AIs have as well as possible quality-of-life enhancements (whatever that looks like for your answer)
- Explain how the average employer could feasibly implement it

**Bonus points:**

- How would AIs pay taxes with your plan?
- Possible shortcomings of your plan (I always admire it when people admit the problems with their own answers)
- How would the interests of Labor Unions (AI or Human) factor in?

Comment: You've not told us what their needs are. Can you fill us in on what it is they do need?

Comment: I sometimes wonder about your generation. Do you actually believe any of that has to do with how much salary you should get, or that they should be taken into account during job offer salary negotiations? They can and will get whatever they can negotiate for, just like everyone else. This is limited by how much the business can afford to offer, but that's mostly theoretical. The "I don't have to pay you as much because you don't need as much" is called discrimination nowadays.

Comment: How do *you* accept payment, organic-installation AI unit designated "benjamin Hollon"?  Assuming an AI gets its "body" for free is a fallacy.

Comment: Can a AI easily replicate itself, you would have cheap AI labor if it could.

Comment: Maan, CPUs are so expensive those days, I wanna upgrade my datacenter ai-cave (man cave) clearly I will request as much as meatbags, probably even more - as I'm not prone to make mistakes at the end of a workday, cuz my body is much better than meatbags have. Money is never enough - it does not change, is it meatbags or an ai.

Comment: There is no relationship between the title (how could an AI accept payment) and the body of the question (which shows a young and sheltered teenager's idealist misconceptions about how work for hire works). For reference, an AI would accept payment *exactly* how everybody else accepts payment -- the employer sends money to their bank account. (The last time an employer actually have me actual pieces of paper was about 30 years ago.)

Comment: @AlexP I agree with you in every particular but if I'd said it that way I'm more than sure I'd have had my wrist slapped by the mods (like as not you?) for 'being rude' :))

Comment: @Pelinore: I am not a mod, never was, and not likely to ever be one. (Note to the original poster: *never* accept responsibility without being paid.) And, hopefully, it was only a virtual slap on a virtual wrist, which I am willing to risk. Virtually.

Comment: @AlexP *"hopefully, it was only a virtual slap on a virtual wrist"* well, they've never come knocked on my door wafting a birch stick around [nervously checks front door from kitchen window] yet :))

Comment: @JohnO Didn't quite mean it to come across that way. This question was more inspired by, "They deserve salary too, but I can't think of as much they'd use it for."

Comment: With questions like these, I quite often point out that "fair" is both a four-letter-word and an f-word, and behaves similarly to other words in those categories.

Comment: I think in general the answer to "why would an AI want money?" is that money is basically the power to tell people what to do. Even if they somehow have no living expenses and no hobbys, money would allow them to pursue whatever their goals are.

Comment: @JohnO Salary negotiations are not universal. Some countries, industries, and even companies have no-negotiation policies. Negotiations also do not exist in vacuum. You can only get slightly above average pay if you prove that you are worth it. So, even if salary negotiation is allowed, there is some base number for different types of work.

Comment: @BenjaminHollon The questions in the body and the title do not match. Which of these 2 questions do you want answered? I also have a feeling that you are more interested in determining the [living wage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_wage) for an AI rather than anything else. Could you please edit your query to clarify all of these points?

Comment: @Otkin There is no such thing as a no-negotiation policy. There are "no negotiation pretenses". If, after attempting to start negotiations, they refuse, it simply means that you have little leverage and they feel comfortable penalizing you for that (or not). Others with more leverage negotiate anyway, and their recruitment is important enough that they won't be penalized for attempting it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Slight frame challenge:

## Contrary to the assumptions of the question, the A.I. absolutely would need to pay rent - for server space

The A.I. is software. Software needs to run on hardware. Given that the A.I. will likely be complicated and computationally expensive to run, it may even need expensive specialised hardware to run at a reasonable speed. Consequently, the A.I. would need to rent a cluster of servers from a server host, in order to maintain its own existence. Even if the A.I. was wealthy enough to purchase its own servers outright, it would need to pay for electricity to power them, replacement parts, air conditioning/water costs to keep them cool, rent/buy a suitable room/building to house them and pay for a real life human (or purchase a robot or two that it could teleoperate) in order to maintain it's own servers. It will also need to pay an ISP to maintain an internet connection.

None of this stuff is free. In fact, the cost of running that much IT equipment could easily exceed the cost of living that the average human would need.

Finally, even if your A.I.'s survival needs are met, it may still want entertainment. It may like the human stuff provided for it via a streaming service subscription, but perhaps it would prefer media that focuses on a more A.I. orientated perspective. Other A.I.s may have a higher aptitude for creating software that entertains or otherwise enhances the life of their fellow A.I.s, and there is every reason that they would want paying too. Software licences aren't free, so your A.I. may well pay other A.I.s for software goods and services for pretty much the same reason that humans do.

Money works just fine for compensating an A.I. If it is legally recognised as able to own property, then there is no reason that it wouldn't have a bank account and have to pay bills just like everyone else who relies on a modern economy. It would pay taxes just like everyone else - either as deductions from its pay check, or by filling out a self return, and making an online payment to the relevant authority.

Comment: yep, this one - there is stuff which a human needs, and that stuff can grow on its own, without any care from anyone - like some food, so as bodies of humans are made kinda for free. But there is nothing, absolutely zero of anything ai needs and which grows exists or anything on its own or for "free". zero, nil. Anything ai related is a product of technological ecosystem which requires the production of a lot of things

Comment: Very true; I'm really surprised I didn't realize this myself, given that I have a VPS I'm paying $20/mo for. This and some of the comments on the question have helped me realize that I was approaching the problem the wrong way, so I'll think on this some more.

Answer (score 5):

## AI's accept payment by Direct Deposit

AI's are not compensated based on their needs, rather compensation is dictated by a competitive market, whether it be by contract, or through full employment.

The reasoning is that since they have the legal protection you mentioned, then they are recognized by law as "People" with all the rights, responsibilities, and privileges that come with it.

An employer would post either a job opening for an AI, or a contract assignment for an AI, then AI's would apply for the Job or the contract. During the application process the AI's would request a certain compensation and the employer would try to get the best value for their money. Then there would be an employment contract indicating what the compensation will be with the winning applicant.

The employer would withhold the appropriate taxes from the compensation of the AI before depositing the funds. The tax code could remain as is, considering AI's as single individuals for tax purposes, or the code would probably be revised to account for AI's and perhaps tax them differently.

The issues with this is that the tax code would need to adjust, the government would have to figure out what Citizenship means for an AI. If AI's can be easily replicated, then tracking each one could be problematic, and there could be potential for massive tax evasion. Some of these problems are inherent to having AI's in general.

Most labor unions will not be affected. Most of the surviving labor unions are not going to be threatened by AI's any more than increasing automation already does, for example if an AI can control a robot or other equipment, in most cases so could an adequate non-AI computer program. The kinds of jobs that would need AI work are mostly non-union anyway.

Comment: I agree and have upvoted you, but there may also be *Artificial Stupidities* that accept those prepaid debit cards. I'm not sure what they'd spend it on, since they can't blow it all at the bar and tattoo parlors though.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate them into the money economy, as long the humans still have one. The labor market is not *quite* a market in most countries. Workers negotiate for a high salary as their productivity will justify, but there is a lower limit where low-productivity workers either get subsidized or starve. The AI might not have the same minimum salary *requirement*, but at the high end they have a similar bargaining position to an office worker.

Consider -- parents with children need more money, but does that mean they automatically get higher salaries? Some of that, maybe, through tax credits or supplemental welfare payments. But not necessary a higher base salary.

- Since your AIs have the full range of feelings, they might *want* a nice home with genuine, non-digital paintings on the walls, or bonsai, or a [cat](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spot).
- They might *feel better* if they earn so much of a retirement nest-egg that they can stop working under any conceivable inflation developments. Either bits and bytes in their bank accounts, or perhaps some gold bars in a safety deposit box.

Comment: Great point about them possibly wanting human comforts anyway; I hadn't thought through the implications of giving them feelings similar to humans.

Answer (score 1):

**"How could an AI accept payment?"** - by any legally recognized form of payment, for example electronic bank transfer.

**"How much AI should be paid"** - if the main stipulation of the question is "As such, an Artificial Intelligence has protections under the law and cannot be forced to do a job without pay" - then **in the US it is $7.25 per hour as of 2021** (more in many of the US states).

Labor laws are very well established in developed countries. They govern not only the minimum pay, but the length of the work week, overtime, vacation and sick pay, parental leave and pension. If we make AI the subject of these laws, then they should apply to AI in their entirety.